# Website slowing down when many users access simultaneously

Tags: mysql, performance, shared-hosting

I'm new to web development. I have hosted my website through a free web hosting service providing free subdomain. The free hosting service says that they provide 100 GB bandwidth. I just upload files to the website using ftp (filezilla).

When the website is accessed one user at a time, the website functions properly, but when many users access the website simultaneously, the website slows down considerably.

---

The details of their server are:

```
Web server  Cowboy
HTTP response code  200
Server Address  http://hostingsiteforfree.com
cache-control   no-store, no-cache
connection  close
content-length  16312
content-type    text/html; charset=utf-8
date    Fri, 17 Oct 2014 13:36:45 GMT
etag    W/"JWDUj6JS+NPPLEYN43WfRQ=="
expires 0
pragma  no-cache
server  Cowboy
via 1.1 vegur
x-content-type-options  nosniff
x-download-options  noopen
x-frame-options DENY
x-xss-protection    1; mode=block
Time to contact web server  0.407361 seconds
```

---

The following information is shown in the control panel of the free hosting service right now:

Server Load: 12.93

MySQL Server Load: 0.14
Apache Version: Apache/2.2.17
PHP Version: 5.3
MySQL Version: 5.1.58

---

Data is inserted or retrieved from mysql database using ajax according to user actions on the website.

What could be possible reasons for the website to respond slowly when multiple users access it simultaneously?

Is it problem of the subdomain? Do I have to buy a domain name?

Is it a problem of the free hosting service?

Do many database requests at the same time cause a problem?

What are server or database requirements when around 50 users would be using the website simultaneously?

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE to diagnose your problem as it can be a variety of things.

Comment: @thanasisk Please can you list the few major among those

Comment: Prime suspect? *your* code :-) - really you provide little details so it is IMPOSSIBLE I say again.

Comment: @thanasisk what details are needed?

Comment: version/settings of MySQL, your webserver version, specs of the server (if applicable) and so on. But the prime suspect is usually the code - even modest setups can serve a few users with proper codebase.

Comment: @thanasisk Server Load: 12.93
MySQL Server Load: 0.14
Apache Version: Apache/2.2.17
PHP Version: 5.3
MySQL Version: 5.1.58 This is information shown in the control panel of the free hosting service right now

Comment: do a top and paste your results - load of 12.93 can be considered high. Basically, your server is working like a "madman", so to speak while the DB server is idling. Debug the Web Server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17946/discussion-between-thanasisk-and-engineer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

You get what you pay for. That server is likely loaded to the brim with other users all making use of the hosting, so there's not much you can do but try another provider or host yourself.